# Visual Studio 2008 Security Update installation Issue KB 971092

Tags: visual-studio, windows-update

Posting this so this can be here for others.

Just noticed - today that I have been in a cycle of downloading KB971092 and installing with reboot.

7 times - 350Mb file. fsk!

Hotfix KB 971092 for Visual Studio 2008 SP1 install problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Applies to:
    Security Update for Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Service Pack 1 (KB971092) 
Symptoms:
    The update installs successfully and but will be offered again by Windows Update as a new update. This can be repeated indefinitely.
    or
    the standalone installer tells you that this update "does not apply, or is blocked by another condition on your system".

1. Download the stand-alone version of . [VS90SP1-KB971092-x86.exe](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=en&FamilyID=294de390-3c94-49fb-a014-9a38580e64cb)
2. Start the installation VS90SP1-KB971092-x86.exe
3. Wait for the error message to come up – do not close the window
4. Copy the temp. folder where the patch has been unpacked to a new folder, for example onto your desktop.
5. Close VS90SP1-KB971092-x86.exe that you started in step 2.
6. Navigate to {Program Files}\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools and find vsvars32.bat.
7. Change the permissions on the file to allow everyone to edit it.
8. Start VS90SP1-KB971092-x86.msp from within the saved folder and the process should complete.
9. You may want to reset permissions that you gave in step 7.

Answer (score 0):

170 people have now indicated that they have experianced this problem. If you have been unable to install VS90SP1-KB971092-x86.exe, please register at  https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=478117 if you have not already done so.

Answer (score 0):

KB971092 was reissued on August 3rd to correct this issue.  It's no longer necessary to perform the workaround.

Comment: As of the 16th of August, Windows Update is still failing to install KB971092. YMMV

Answer (score 0):

I had this same error with Windows 10 Technical Preview 9879.  Downloaded the stand-alone update from Microsoft and ran it.  This install required mounting my VS2008 ISO (Using Virtual Clone Drive) and it installed just fine.